# Your session may have been lost due to a time-out or a server failure. in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

Recently we migrated Sitecore 8.0 to 8.1. We are facing below issue in Sitecore 8.1.

While adding Images to page, I am getting below error.

[image: The operation could not be completed. Your session may have been lost due to a time-out or a server failure.]

**[The operation could not be completed.
Your session may have been lost
due to a time-out or a server failure.
Try again.]**

Comment: Something in the log file?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue on our clean install of 8.1 after having been on 8.0 for some time. The issue is likely due to having bot detection enabled on your CM server.

The fix:

1. Edit `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` on your CM server
2. Set `Analytics.AutoDetectBots` to **false**

As of 26 April 2016, this is a known documentation bug under 8.1 that Sitecore has queued for resolution.

Refer to the 8.0 Documentation on Configuring a CM Server:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server

Compared with 8.1 Documentation for the same:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server

The 8.1 docs made no mention of updating the `Analytics.AutoDetectbots` setting to prevent CM users from hitting bot session timeout.