# How to prevent error message after custom UI in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2, sitecore9

I've built a content editor XML UI element. I launch it via a command with the code

```
string url = Sitecore.UIUtil.GetUri("control:CloneToMarkets") + "&id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(id) + "&path=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path) + "&database=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(database);
Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowModalDialog(url, "400px", "700px", string.Empty, true);
```

In my DialogForm class I'm overriding OnLoad() and OnOK(). With on load I'm invoking its base method at the start of the class, and OnOk ends with the base method.

If I "ok", "cancel" or "X" on the custom DialogForm I get this error:
[image]

My dialog works fine, and completes its purpose, I'm just getting this error afterwards. Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you experience a known problem when Sitecore Client users get mistakenly categorised as robots.

Usually, it happens when Sitecore Analytics is enabled and users do not visit the site front-end before logging into the Sitecore Client. In this situation, the current session may be mistakenly identified as a robot visit and will cause the admin session expiration as Sitecore Analytics reduces session timeout for robot visits aiming to minimise the server resources utilisation.

So, make sure that `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.RobotDetection.config` is disabled on your CM instance and also make the following changes in `web.config`:

1. In `system.web/httpModules` node, `name="MediaRequestSessionModule"` change the following line **from**
   *"Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection"*
   **to** `"Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics"`.
2. In `system.webServer/modules` node, `name="MediaRequestSessionModule"` change the following line **from**
   *"Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection"*
   **to** `"Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics"`.

Also, take a look at similar posts here:

- [Your session may have been lost due to a time-out or a server failure. in Sitecore 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797686/your-session-may-have-been-lost-due-to-a-time-out-or-a-server-failure-in-siteco)
- https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6383/can-sitecore-be-customized-to-auto-save-pages-including-the-rich-text-editor